# Xcode Stopped Recognizing Global Variables - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, global-variables

I've been working on an app for over a month and have many variables defined at the top of the Swift document that came with my tabbed interface template in XCODE. I've declared various UIColors to be used globally and have made a few classes where I draw a few different icon shapes. All of a sudden today Xcode is throwing up red errors of "Use of unresolved identifier [one of my UIColor variabls]" for all of my colors used throughout my drawing classes. I've tried to clean the project and restart Xcode Any idea what could be going on?

Here are my global variables:

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

//----Global Variables----
var timerMode = "start"
var arrowButtonTapped = false
var timerButtonTouched = false
var currentView = "brew it"

//--------My Colors -----------
let colorGreen = UIColor(red: 0.310, green: 0.725, blue: 0.624, alpha: 1.000)
let colorLightGreen = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 217/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 100)
var colorRed = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 93/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 100)
let colorDarkBlue = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 29/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1.0)
let colorOrange = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 162/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
let colorTransparent = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 162/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 0.0)

//----Countdown times----
var countTime : NSTimeInterval = 6
var halfCountTime : NSTimeInterval = countTime * 0.5
var okCountTime : NSTimeInterval = 2


//---- End Global Variables ----

//let cup1Graphic = coffeeMugVector()
//let cup2Graphic = coffeeMugVector()
//let cup3Graphic = coffeeMugVector()
//let cup4Graphic = coffeeMugVector()
//let cup5Graphic = coffeeMugVector()
//let cup6Graphic = coffeeMugVector()



//Coffe Cups x Coffee Strength returns amount of coffee as an integer
class coffeeCalculator {
    var selectedCups = 0
    var cupSelect = false
    let coffeeStronger = 20
    var coffeeStrength = 15
    let coffeeWeaker = 15
    var water = 226

    //var cupAnimation = CSAnimationView(type:"morph", duration:0.5, delay:0)

    // What to do when a cup is selected
    func cupSelected() {
        if cupSelect == true{
            selectedCups++
        }
        else if selectedCups > 0{
            selectedCups--
        }
        println("\(selectedCups)")
    }

    //take coffee cups multiplied by coffee strength and return the amount as a string

    //Calcualte coffee and return an attributed string
    func coffeeTextOnly() ->String {
        var calculatedCoffee = selectedCups * coffeeStrength
        var coffeeToString = "\(calculatedCoffee)"
        return coffeeToString
    }

    func calculateCoffee() -> (NSMutableAttributedString) {
        var calculatedCoffee = selectedCups * coffeeStrength
        var coffeeToString = "\(calculatedCoffee)"

        //Convert the CoffeeCalculator output to an attributed string
        var coffeeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:coffeeToString)

        //Part 2 set the font attributes for the lower case g
        var coffeeTypeFaceAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)]

        //Part 3 create the "g" character and give it the attributes that you set up
        var coffeeG = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"g", attributes:coffeeTypeFaceAttributes)
        coffeeText.appendAttributedString(coffeeG)

        return (coffeeText)
    }

    //Calculate teh amount of water needed and return it as a string
    func calculateWater() -> (NSMutableAttributedString) {
        var calculatedWater = water * selectedCups
        var waterToString = "\(calculatedWater)"

        var waterText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:waterToString)

        //Part 2 set the font attributes for the lower case g
        var waterTypeFaceAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)]

        //Part 3 create the "g" character and give it the attributes that you set up
        var waterG = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"g", attributes:waterTypeFaceAttributes)
        waterText.appendAttributedString(waterG)

        return (waterText)
    }
}

////----BEGIN GRAPHICS ----////


//----Main Timer (circle) Button----//
@IBDesignable
class timerButtonGraphics: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var bounds = self.bounds
        var center = CGPoint()
        center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2
        center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2
        var radius = 31
        var path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: CGFloat(0.0), endAngle: CGFloat(Float(M_PI) * 2.0), clockwise: true)
        path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 0)
        path.lineWidth = 1
        if timerMode == "reset" || timerMode == "ok" {
            colorRed.setStroke()
            colorRed.setFill()
        }
        else {
            colorGreen.setStroke()
            colorGreen.setFill()
        }
        if timerButtonTouched == true {
                path.lineWidth = 2
                path.fill()
            }
        path.stroke()
    }
}


//------Arrow Button------//
@IBDesignable
class arrowButtonGraphic: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(20.36, 2.68))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(2.69, 20.23))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(2.69, 28.32), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0.44, 22.46), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0.44, 26.09))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(10.84, 28.32), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(4.94, 30.56), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(8.59, 30.56))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(22.71, 16.53))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(26.29, 16.53), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(23.7, 15.55), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(25.3, 15.56))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(38.16, 28.32))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(46.31, 28.32), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(40.41, 30.56), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(44.06, 30.56))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(46.31, 20.23), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(48.56, 26.09), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(48.56, 22.46))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(28.64, 2.68))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(24.48, 1), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(27.49, 1.54), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(25.98, 0.98))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(20.36, 2.68), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(22.99, 0.99), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(21.5, 1.55))
        bezierPath.closePath()
        bezierPath.miterLimit = 4;

        colorGreen.setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
        bezierPath.stroke()
        colorGreen.setFill()
        //Rotate arrow if on "weigh it" page
        if arrowButtonTapped == true {
            bezierPath.lineWidth = 2
            bezierPath.stroke()
        }
    }
}

//----Timer Baground Circle ----//
@IBDesignable
class timerBackgroundCircle: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 238, 238))
        colorLightGreen.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }
}

//----Timer Bagkround Mask ----//
@IBDesignable
class timerMask: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let colorGreen = UIColor(red: 0.310, green: 0.725, blue: 0.624, alpha: 1.000)
        let colorRed = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 93/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 100)
        let colorLightGreen = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 217/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 100)

        //The shape to mask out
        /*var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 238, height: 238))
        colorGreen.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()*/

        //The rectangle
        var bounds : CGRect = self.bounds
        var maskRect = CAShapeLayer()
        maskRect.frame = bounds
        //maskRect.fillColor = colorLightGreen.CGColor

        //The circle mask
        var maskCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 40, y: 150, width: 238, height: 238))
        maskCirclePath.appendPath(UIBezierPath(rect: bounds))
        //combine appended path to rectangle path
        maskRect.path = maskCirclePath.CGPath
        colorRed.setFill()
        maskCirclePath.fill()
        maskRect.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        self.layer.mask = maskRect
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my classes are being declared correctly. I made a group called "Vectors" where I planned to make a separate class for each drawing. I'm not sure if i'm supposed to select file -> new -> file and select a Cocoa Touch Class, or if i can just create a blank Swift file and write out my class code from scratch there. This is the option I was trying to figure out when my globial variables "went bad".

What's more strange is that the app compiles just fine in the simulator, my colors appear correctly for the classes applied to my icons that use the global color variables. But Xcode is throwing a fit so my @IBDesignables won't compile in storyboard and I have a bunch of red errors.

*UPDATE*
Somewhere along the way here, the Swift file that I posted in my question was removed from my projects "tests" target membership. The little checkbox was unchecked. I have no idea how I could have done this, but everything was back to normal until i got an xcode error whiting out all of my text and saying that editing is currently disabled. I ended up removing all of my swift files from "tests" (unchecking the "tests" target membership for all of the files"), then creating a new Objective C file which prompted Xcode to ask me to configure a new bridging header I transferred my old bridging header code to the new file. This seems to have fixed the problem. I'm not submitting this an an answer because I don't know what the actual problem was.

Comment: Can you show one or more of these definitions? Could be a syntax error somewhere in the file that contains them, which might invalidate other parts of that file's code.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your class please?

Comment: I updated my question with the complete class. I am getting errors in the other class files of my project where I try to use the global variables. Like is said, the project compiles properly in the simulator